# Passed variable in onSaveInstanceState() is cleared in onDestroy

Tags: android, android-activity, savestate

I asked this question: [savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList() return empty list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26612840/savedinstancestate-getparcelablearraylist-return-empty-list)

But now, I found that this problem is related to my **onDestroy()** method.

I save my ArrayList called **mVideos** in **onSaveInstanceState()** and clear all it's items inside

**onDestroy** (I thought doing this will save memory when app is killed).

In **onCreate()** I restore saved **mVideos**, BUT It returned empty list

My Code:

```
   @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onDestroy();

    if (mVideos != null)
        mVideos.clear();

    mVideos = null;
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle out) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    out.putParcelableArrayList(VIDEO_LIST, mVideos);
    super.onSaveInstanceState(out);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        ArrayList<Video> saved = savedInstanceState.getParcelableArrayList(VIDEO_LIST);
       Log.e(VIDEO_LIST, "Count: " + saved.size());
    }
}
```

--> **saved.size() = 0**. If I remove **mVideos.clear()** in onDestroy() it works correctly

I know that onSaveInstanceState() is called right after onPause(). BUT why in this case, why onDestroy

effects to saved variable?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that in `onSaveInstanceState` Android saves a **pointer** to the memory area, so when you calling **mVideos.clear()**, that memory area is clearing, and when you trying to restore it, it returns an empty list.

Comment: Yes, do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I suggest that you shouldn't clear the list and set it to null. If Android decides that it doesn't have enough memory it will destroy your list automatically :) Just don't care about it.

Comment: I thought about this. I should keep searching for an other better solutions :)

Comment: Another solution is to store your list in the database or SharedPreferences, then you will be able to clear your list. But I think if you don't see bad behavior of your phone, just forget about it :D

Comment: addition question: Do you know why **onSaveInstanceState()** is called if we rotate screen, BUT if we exit app by pressing BACK key, this method will be never called?

Comment: Sure. When you rotate the screen your activity is immediately destroying, so the **onDestroy()** method will be called. Then your activity also immediately recreating calling **onCreate()**. That's why **onSaveInstanceState()** is immediately calling. But when you press the BACK button, your activity is **NOT DESTROYING**, so the **onDestroy()** method not calling, just **onStop()**, but **onDestroy()** method **will be** called when Android decides that it doesn't have enough memory and kill your app.

Comment: I  suggest you  to read this article about android lifecycle http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63835/discussion-between-binngokute-and-romadja).